# create a list of object in Cython

Tags: python, list, object, cython

I want to know how I can create a list of C object in Cython.

This simple example working:

cimport cython

```
b = real_test()
print(b)

cdef real_test():
    cdef int a
    cdef Node b = Node()
    a = b.h
    return a

cdef class Node:
    cdef int h
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.h = 3
```

but not this:

```
cimport cython

b = real_test()
print(b)

cdef real_test():
    cdef int a
    cdef Node *b = [Node(),Node(),Node()]
    a = b[0].h
    return a

cdef class Node:
    cdef int h
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.h = 3
```

How to do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure is right but it's work:

```
cimport cython

b = real_test()
print(b)

cdef real_test():
    cdef int a
    cdef list b = [Node(),Node(),Node()]
    a = b[0].h
    return a

cdef class Node:
    cdef int h
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.h = 3
    property h:
        def __get__(self):
          return self.h
        def __set__(self, float value):
          self.h = value
```